# I'm relatively new to JSON, and I cannot find what is wrong with mine

Tags: json, google-chrome

I'm trying to create my own theme fro Google Chrome, so I copy-pasted a JSON and just changed values for colours, etc.  but now, I'm getting errors with the lists for RGB colours.  How can I fix this?

```
{
   "name": "TMGS3 Flowers",
   "theme": {
      "colors": {
         "frame": [ 231, 250, 251 ],
         "tab_text": [ 241, 000, 148 ],
         "tab_background_text": [ 250, 194, 129 ],
         "bookmark_text": [ 241, 000, 148 ],
         "ntp_text": [ 241, 000, 148 ],
         "ntp_link": [ 244, 172, 168 ],
         "ntp_section_text": [ 241, 000, 148 ],
         "ntp_section_link": [ 244, 172, 168 ],
         "ntp_section": [ 185, 221, 141 ]
      },
      "images": {
         "theme_frame": "Images/theme_frame.png",
         "theme_ntp_background": "Images/theme_base.png",
         "theme_tab_background": "Images/theme_tabbg.png",
         "theme_toolbar": "Images/theme_toolbar.png"
      },
      "properties": {
         "ntp_background_alignment": "bottom",
         "ntp_background_repeat": "no-repeat",
         "ntp_logo_alternate": 1
      },
      "tints": {
         "buttons": [ 1, 1, 1 ]
      }
   },
   "version": "3"
}
```

Comment: "..getting errors" Which errors? Please, be more specific.

Comment: *I'm getting errors* is a meaningless problem description unless you tell us what those errors are - they're right on the screen in front of you, but we can't see your screen from here. Put them in your question, which we can see.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the format you're giving the `000`. As they're iIntegers, you NEED to use `0` or the JSON will not validate. Ex.:

`"tab_text": [ 241, 0, 148 ]`

If you absolutely need to use this format, consider changing the type to string, if it makes sense for your use case:

`"tab_text": [ "241", "000", "148" ]`

Answer (score 0):

Leading zeroes are not allowed in JSON numbers (see https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf), so you have to replace every instance of `000` with just `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Validating the JSON using: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ highlights one potential issue, which is that 000 is an invalid number. Switching to using 0 instead for these numbers makes the JSON valid.